# What Laravel cache do I need to clear to remove error about missing migration file?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I've got a couple of migrations for tables within my app. The tables are:

- people
- skills
- media
- notes

There is a one to many relationship between `people` and each of the other tables.

```
// The people table definition

Schema::create('people', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->primary('id');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});


// the skill table definition with the foreign key constraint referencing people

Schema::create('skills', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id');
    $table->primary('id');
    $table->uuid('person_id');
    $table->foreign('person_id')
            ->references('id')->on('people')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I was creating the migrations via `artisan` I accidentally created the `skills` migration file before the `people` migration.

This caused a problem because when you run `php artisan migrate`, the files are fired in timestamp order and if a primary key is not established before a foreign key constraint is defined you get an error, e.g.

The file:

```
2016_02_24_174227_create_people_table.php
```

Will fire *after* the file:

```
2016_02_24_174221_create_skills_table.php
```

Because the `skills` file has a smaller timestamp prefix in the name (17:42:21 comes before 17:42:27). This means the foreign key constraint in `skills` is looking for a primary key in `people` that doesn't exist yet.

So to fix that, I renamed the file `2016_02_24_174227_create_people_table.php` to `2016_02_24_170000_create_people_table.php`.

This fix worked, but now whenever I `php artisan migrate:refresh` my tables, I get an error saying that artisan is somehow still looking for the old people file:

[image: artisan error]

I tried clearing the application cache with `php artisan cache:clear`, but I still get the error.

Is there a particular cache I need to clear to remove the reference to the original migration file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not a cache issue. You just have to run composer again:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: *facepalm* I forgot that the migrations are part of a composer classmap. Thanks for the help. I'll give you a check once I'm able to. You answered so fast that the time limit isn't up :P

Comment: I had the same issue and this help me a LOT, thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me; `php artisan migrate` is still giving a warning about a migration that exists on another code branch.

Answer (score 3):

Rollback your migration and check

```
migrate:rollback
```